# Mathematica and CUDA

Tags: cuda, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

Is it possible that built in functions in Mathematica (like `Minimize[expr,{x1,x2,...}]`) will start to work via CUDA after installation of CUDA module for Mathematica?

Comment: See CUDALink/tutorial/Functions in Help Browser for list of functions that use CUDA

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't believe so, no. Mathematica's CUDALink module currently provides only a handful of GPU accelerated functions - some basic image processing operations, BLAS style linear algebra calls, Fourier Transforms and simple parallel reductions (argmin, argmax, and summation). There is also tools for integrating user written CUDA code, and for generating CUDA code symbolically. Outside of that, the rest of Mathematica's core functionality remains CPU only.

You can see full details of current CUDA and OpenCL support [here](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/cuda-and-opencl-support/).

Comment: Thanks for the edit-Fu, I started writing that last sentence in one sense and got distracted by a phone call, then finished it in the other sense.

Comment: I do that all the time.  Often I decide to change how I am going to write something several times before I get it written the first time.  Bits and pieces of each form get left behind, and I fail to realize it.